# T-SQL MIN on Date type resulting in INT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a column called ThisDayOfTherapy which is of datatype DATE in SQL Server.
Later, I have an aggregate query using Min(ThisDayOftherapy).  This query populates a #temp table with the result of Min(ThisDayOfTherapy) as column name StartDate_Min

In a 3rd location I am finally doing something with StartDate_Min.  When I hold my mouse over StartDate_Min, it says the datatype is INT.

Shouldn't it simply be DATE?  Will it still work as if it were a date for all practical purposes?

Comment: An aggregate will NOT change the datatype of the expression provided to the function. There must be some transformation or misunderstanding that you don't realize or perhaps a bug in the tool you are using that shows the datatype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the same behavior, but I think you will be fine. SQL Server would not execute any date functions if it was not a valid date. Adding one day to my MinDate column from my temp table is working as expected.

[image]